# How to Whats App an image that is in image view from image gallery?

Tags: java, android, image, whatsapp

I can select any image from the gallery with the help of the given code and insert the selected image into an image view.

For getting an image from Gallery i use this code that work perfect.

```
     btnGetImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
             takeImage.launch(intent);

    //After getting image in image view When the image is received, then 
                //it becomes WhatsApp immediately Which we don't want. We want to 
               // WhatsApp the obtained result through another button.

     Uri imgUri = result.getData().getData();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                intent.setType("text/plain");
                intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
                intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                            "Whatsapp have not been installed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
         }
     });

      ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> takeImage = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        result-> {
            if ( result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK && result.getData() != null){
                Uri uri = result.getData().getData();
                ivImage.setImageURI(uri);
            }
        }
);
```

As you can see we get the image and then instantly Whats App it. But the purpose of my question is that we first get the image from the gallery. When we see the image in the image view, then if we want, we can Whats App it or change it again and Whats App it with other send button.

Comment: You better remember the uri and then share the uri to that app.

Comment: Else you have to get bitmap from the view. Save that bitmap to file. Get an uri for it using a file provider and then share that uri.

Comment: Please will you explain with sample code? Thanks

Comment: Which one? As i suggested two ways. Be exact.

Comment: Through save that bitmap to file and then

Comment: That are at least four steps. For which of them you need help?

Comment: I have no ideal about this . Please if you don't mind then help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
    Uri imgUri = result.getData().getData();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
    intent.setType("image/jpeg");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    try {
        activity.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        ToastHelper.MakeShortText("Whatsapp have not been installed.");
    }
```

for more description check this [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-images-directly-to-whatsapp-in-android/)

Comment: I will inform you by checking in the app.

Comment: Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath());  What is image path file ?

Comment: You should of course use your own uri as i said in my first comment: `Uri uri = result.getData().getData();`; Step four of the four.

Comment: I edit my answer. Instead of getting Uri from the file you can directly use uri from activity result like below.
```Uri imgUri = result.getData().getData();```

Comment: BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) ivImage.getDrawable();
                 Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
                 Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(bitmap));
                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                 intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "The text you wanted to share");
                 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
                 intent.setType("image/jpeg");
                 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

Comment: But the error is " File Format not supported "

Comment: Please see my updated Question. Thanks